# Trouble loading font in django templates

Tags: css, django, import, django-templates, font-face

okay so, my

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and this is what is in my project folder.

```
.:
mange.py project projectApp

./projectApp:
__init__.py
models.py
views.py
urls.py
tests.py
static
templates

./projectApp/static:
css

./projectApp/static/css:
consola.ttf style.css

./projectApp/templates:
base.html
```

I am also having trouble imoporting style.css. I tried

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
```

but it doesn't work.

in my style.css, I am trying to import the font by doing this

```
@font-face { font-family: consola; src: url('consola.ttf'); }
```

My STATIC_URL is

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and my STATIC_ROOT is

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/documents/project/projectApp/static'
```

but it is not working. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Don't keep your static folder inside template, move it next to template folder, then try the second path again.

Comment: Okay I edited my post and placed both the templates and static folder inside of projectApp.. can you look at it agian?

Comment: Try `url('css/consola.ttf')`

Comment: Okay so I realized it might be that my template isn't even loading the CSS in the first place. I created a new thread asking why the template isn't loading the CSS. can you have a look at it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203002/djnago-loading-css-from-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found the answer. To link the CSS correctly, I was supposed to do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}" />
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
```

Comment: You need to approve your own response, so the post will get resolved.

Comment: Actually your "incorrect" link will work if you define a STATICFILES_DIR and a STATIC_URL in your settings file. If in development environment, you also need to include some code in urls.py to serve your static files. Read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/