# Django loading css from template

Tags: css, django, import, django-templates, font-face

okay so my base.html template is in

```
/home/user/documents/project/app/templates/base.html
```

and my style.css is in

```
/home/user/documents/project/app/static/css/style.css
```

and my consola.ttf font is in

```
/home/user/documents/project/app/static/fonts/consola.ttf
```

My static_URL is

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and my STATIC_ROOT is

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/documents/project/app/static'
```

now, how do I link the style.css to my base.html template?
I tried doing

but it didn't work. Also, how do I load the consola.ttf font in my style.css?
Since both style.css and the consola.ttf font are in the same static folder, I tried doing

```
@font-face { font-family: consola; src: url(../../fonts/consola.ttf'); }
```

but that didn't work either. Any idea on how to fix these two problems?

Here is the beginning of my .html template.

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
        <title>{% block title %}Name{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
```

that's how it should be, right?

Comment: what did you try doing for linking the style.css to your base.html template?

Comment: I tried <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" /> but that didn't work

Comment: do you have `django.core.context_processors.static` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR`?

Comment: Ah, okay I didn't so i'm guessing that was the problem.

Comment: okay nevermind, the problem is still there, the CSS is still not linking for some reason. I put up the beginning of my  .html template.. it looks correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay found the answer. I was supposed to do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}" />
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
```